# How to create a shortcode with 1 parameter (atts)

Tags: shortcode, parameter

I am having trouble getting a shortcode to work with 1 attribute.

Here is my shortcode `[sme_user-email userID="2"]`

Here are my scripts - none of them work.

```
function getUserEmail_func($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('userID' => 1,), $atts));
    $user_info = get_userdata($atts);
    return $user_info->user_email;
}
add_shortcode('sme_user-email', 'getUserEmail_func');
```

.

```
function getUserEmail_func($atts) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($atts);
    return $user_info->user_email;
}
add_shortcode('sme_user-email', 'getUserEmail_func');
```

.

```
function getUserEmail_func($atts) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($atts['userID]');
    return $user_info->user_email;
}
add_shortcode('sme_user-email', 'getUserEmail_func');
```

This one works -- but I do not want to hardcode the user ID. I was hoping to be able to do it dynamically

```
function getUserEmail_func($atts) {
    $user_info = get_userdata(2);
    return $user_info->user_email;
}
add_shortcode('sme_user-email', 'getUserEmail_func');
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is how you should create shortcode.

First you will have to define `$atts` item in `get_userdata` because `$atts` is an array. Also I think there is also some issues with uppercase attributes names, so you should use attribute in lower case. So instead of `userID`, use `userid`.

```
function getUserEmail_func( $atts ) {
    $user_info = get_userdata( $atts['userid'] );
    return $user_info->user_email;
}
add_shortcode( 'sme_user-email', 'getUserEmail_func' );
```

Have tested it and it's working.

Comment: Amazing @Roberthue...UPPERCASE is an issue. I would have never figured that one out.

Comment: Sometimes it is. That's why usually avoid uppercase and combination of dashes `-`, like you used in shortcode name `sme_user-email`. You used one hyphen and one underscore. Keep it uniform, and you will face less issues.