# Wordpress: How to create custom REST API route?

Tags: rest-api

How can we create custom REST API route for sending specific data format to  **Android** or **IOS** app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create route using `rest_api_init` action like :

Simply add below code to your theme `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wp/v2', 'forgot_password', array(
        'methods' => array('GET', 'POST'),
        'callback' => 'forgot_password'
    ));
} );

function forgot_password(){
    // YOUR CALLBACK FUNCTION STUFF HERE
}
```

**forgot_password** will define route URL address.

**methods** will define which method u want get request parameters like **GET** or **POST**.

**callback** will define callback function which is call when rest api will fire.

Comment: Could you mention more about the shortcode such as  "forgot_password" ? where do we put our arguments ?

Comment: @RajuyourPepe this question is not for create shortcode so if you looking for create shortcode in wordpress then please check **https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172919/how-to-create-a-shortcode-with-1-parameter-atts**