# Update user meta via REST API?

Tags: rest-api

I have a native app project that gets all data from `/wp-json/wp/v2`.

I've registered phone using this

```
register_meta('user', 'phone', array(
    "type" => "string",
    "show_in_rest" => true
));
```

to the functions.php and I can see the user metadata using this

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1
```

How can I create/update the usermeta using WP REST API outside WordPress?

any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look for custom rest api route **https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323890/wordpress-how-to-create-custom-rest-api-route**

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this yesterday, here's how I did it.

Like you have already done `register_meta` to appear in the api.

```php
register_meta('user', 'meta_key', array(
    "type" => "string",
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "single" => true,
));
```

Then you will need to make a POST or PUT request to the users endpoint with the meta values in the body of the request.

I accomplished this using javascript's `fetch` api but you could also do it with `ajax` or using WordPress's `wp_remote_request()` function.

First I enqueued my javascript.

```php
wp_register_script( 'theme-js', get_theme_file_uri( './dist/scripts/main.js' ), [ 'jquery' ], '', true );
wp_localize_script(
    'theme-js',
    'wpApiSettings',
    array(
        'root'        => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ), // Rest api root
        'nonce'       => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ), // For auth
        'currentUser' => get_current_user_id() ?: false,
    )
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-js' );
```

Then I setup my fetch function.

```js
const fetchApi = function(route, data, method) {
  if (!route) route = 'posts'
  if (!method) method = 'GET'

  return fetch(wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/' + route, {
    method,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'X-WP-Nonce': wpApiSettings.nonce,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}
```

Then call the function when you need.

```js
fetchApi(
  `users/${wpApiSettings.currentUser}`,
  {
    meta: {
      meta_key: value
    }
  },
  'POST'
)
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp)
    if (resp.ok) {
      return resp.json()
    }
    return false
  })
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Answer (score 1):

With Wordpress `Version 6.4.3` I had to do the following:

```php
$userMetaProp = 'customMeta';
add_filter('rest_pre_insert_user', static function (
    stdClass        $prepared_user,
    WP_REST_Request $request
) use ($userMetaProp): stdClass {
    if (!empty($request['meta'])) {
        $prepared_user->{$userMetaProp} = [];
        foreach ($request['meta'] as $key => $value) {
            $prepared_user->{$userMetaProp}[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $prepared_user;
}, accepted_args: 2);
add_filter('insert_custom_user_meta', static function (
    array   $custom_meta,
    WP_User $user,
    bool    $update,
    array   $userdata
) use ($userMetaProp): array {
    if (array_key_exists($userMetaProp, $userdata)) {
        foreach ($userdata[$userMetaProp] as $key => $value) {
            $custom_meta[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $custom_meta;
}, accepted_args: 4);
```

Now you can update user meta data with a request like so:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic [AUTH-TOKEN]' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "meta": {
        "option":"theValueForTheOption"
    }
}'
```

You need to change [AUTH-TOKEN] with your own token (see: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/)

### Explanation:

- the first filter `rest_pre_insert_user` get the data in the meta prop of the request and store it in `$prepared_user`
- the second filter `insert_custom_user_meta` use the data in `$userdata` which get his data from `$prepared_user` to return the custom meta data to store in the user

Answer (score 0):

I found these 2 post helpful

- https://www.wpsuperstars.net/wordpress-rest-api/
- https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-rest-api/